# how to use onClick method in another file

Tags: reactjs, react-boilerplate

I need to filter AssessmentCards by Year. I made the method.

But I need to call **clickAllCards** and **clickYearCard** method in onClick event on other file. How can I do that?

This is my code with the methods, I'm using Pug.JS to render:

```
import React from 'react';
import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import messages from './messages';

import { getAssessmentsCards } from '../../functions';

import template from './index.pug';

const cardsAssessments = getAssessmentsCards();

export default class CardAssessment extends React.PureComponent { // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      listCards: [],
      openCm: false,
    }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.setState({listCards: cardsAssessments});
  }

  hover() {
    this.setState({openCm: !this.state.openCm});
  }

  clickAllCards(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({listCards: cardsAssessments});
  }

  clickYearCard(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var filtered = cardsAssessments.filter((data) => {
      return data.yearCard === '2018';
    });
    this.setState({listCards: filtered});
  }

  render() {

    let cm = ["card-menu"];
    if(this.state.openCm) {
      cm.push('active');
    }

    return template.call(this, {
      messages,
      FormattedMessage,
      Link,
      cm
    });
  }
}
```

This is my pug file:

```
.card-adjust
    div(href="" onClick="{this.clickYearCard.bind(this)}") 2018
    div(href="" onClick="{this.clickAllCards.bind(this)}") All
    Link.card.add-new(to="/add-assessment")
        span
            .add-icon
                i.ti-plus
            |
            FormattedMessage(__jsx='{...messages.addAssessment}')
    .card.card-materia(@for='data in this.state.listCards', key='{data.id}')
        .card-body(id="{data.id}")
            div(className="{cm.join(' ')}" onClick="{this.hover.bind(this)}")
                i.fas.fa-ellipsis-v
                .cm-floating
                    Link.cmf-agenda(to="/agendamento")
                        i.ti-agenda
                        |
                        FormattedMessage(__jsx='{...messages.scheduled}')
                    Link.cmf-copy(to="#")
                        i.pe-7s-copy-file
                        |  
                        FormattedMessage(__jsx='{...messages.copy}')
                    Link.cmf-trash(to="#")
                        i.ti-trash
                        | 
                        FormattedMessage(__jsx='{...messages.delete}')
            .cm-icon
                i(className='{data.icon}')
            h2.cm-title {data.disciplineAbbreviation}
            span.badge.badge-danger {data.status}
            p.cm-questions {data.questionNumber} 
                FormattedMessage(__jsx='{...messages.questions}')
            .cm-info
                Link(to="#") {data.disciplineName}
                Link(to="#") {data.year}
                Link(to="#") {data.segment}
            .cm-date
                //- i.pe-7s-refresh-2
                | {data.date}
```

And this is the file where I need to put the onClick event:

```
import React from 'react';
import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';
import messages from './messages';

import template from './index.pug';
import '../../assets/scss/main.scss';


export default function (params = {}) {
  const { messages, FormattedMessage } = params;
  return (
    <div>
      <ul className="nav nav-tabs">
        <li className="nav-item">
          <a className="nav-link" href="#">
            <FormattedMessage {...messages.all} />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <a className="nav-link" href="#">2018</a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <a className="nav-link" href="#">2017</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div className="navigation-tabs display-none">
        <a>
          <i className="nt-icon ti-angle-left" />
        </a>
        1 de 3
        <a>
          <i className="nt-icon ti-angle-right" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with Pug.js but we can use those kind of methods as props in an other Component. We send the method as prop, use that method for onClick event.

Comment: Thank you @devserkan I will try that now.

Comment: It is a very simple and basic step for React, you can find lots of examples. I will provide a very simple one as an answer since I'm sure now you are looking for this answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass any method for onClick event to any component like that:

**App.js**

```
class App extends React.Component {
    handleClick = () => alert( "Clicked" );

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child click={this.handleClick}/>
            </div>
        )
   }
}
```

or with a function component if you don't need lifecylce methods or "this" (here we don't need):

```
const App = () => {
    const handleClick = () => alert( "Clicked" );

    return (
    <div>
        <Child click={handleClick}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Child.js**

```
const Child = ( props ) => (
    <div>
        <button onClick={props.click}>Click me!</button>
    </div>
)
```